# using lazy loading, as include in include and access to LastOrDefault record's atribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, view, include

view

```
<img src="@product.ImageSet.Images.LastOrDefault().ImageUrl" />   not working
<p>@product.ImageSet.Images.count</p>    is working
```

controller

```
using (var balikciContext = new BalikciContext())
        {
            var model = new ProductViewModel
            {
                Products = balikciContext.Products.Include("ImageSet").Include("ImageSet.Images").ToList(),
                Categories = balikciContext.Categories.Where(c => c.ModuleId == 3).ToList()
            };
            return View(model);
        }
```

i have classical error message "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

what's the problem

Comment: LastOrDefault is returning the default, which is null, and you can't call properties on null, so you get the error.

Comment: btw: rendering the view inside the context scope is not, imho, a good practice.

Comment: FWIW, you don't need to separately include `ImageSet` and `ImageSet.Images`. If you just include `ImageSet.Images`, a join is added for `ImageSet` automatically.

Comment: @tschmit007: Agreed. Actually `using` with a context is a bad idea in general. It's stupidly difficult to avoid raising exceptions because something was lazy-loaded unexpectedly. Ideally, your context should be request-bound. Use a dependency injection container to inject it into you controller in request-scope.

Comment: Thanks @RonBeyer it's worked in this    way.....  Products.Include("ImageSet.Images").ToList().Where(p =>p.ImageSet.Images.Count>0)